# Choose where sent and deleted emails go in Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, email

On several iOS and Android email clients, you are able to choose which folder to use for sent, deleted and archived emails. I know this wasn't possible on Windows Phone 8/8.1 and so far I can't seem to find a way to do this on Windows 10 Mobile either.

Can somebody confirm whether or not you can choose what email folders to use on Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: You have it already in outlook, just look better.

Comment: @GlacialMan I often wonder why people like you have time to waste creating accounts on sites like this one

Comment: @GlacialMan I have no idea what you are trying to say. I would welcome your answer though.

Comment: Never mind forgot :)